# WebService doesn't work on ajax call

Tags: ajax, web-services, jquery

I tried to call my web service with a pretty simple ajax call, but no it didn't work.
this is my ajax call:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            var murl = window.location.href;
            var url = murl.replace("http://", "").split("/");
            var filename = url[url.length - 1].substr(0, url[url.length - 1].lastIndexOf("."));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebService.asmx?op=ActivateFuncs", //the url is correct, surely
                data: { url: murl.replace("/", "\\"), filename: filename }, 
                success: function (data) {
                    var d = data;
                    console.log(d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.StatusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And there is my WebService Method:

```
public WebService()
{

}

[WebMethod]
public string ActivateFuncs()
{
    string url = Context.Request["url"], filename = Context.Request["fileame"];
    return "url :" + url + ", file name: " + filename;
}
```

it returns "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Do you have an error message you could provide? Which is more specific than Internal Server Error? This can mean everything.

Comment: What is `error description` of your internal error?

Comment: Is that a typo here, or did you really try to get a value for `Context.Request["fileame"]`?  Also, there's a space in `file name` in your response.  Both those things will break it, but the first will give you a server error.

Comment: hey Yan and Murali, I know it can be anything and this is exactly my problem. I don't know anything about the problem...
Archer, its was just an example. The point is that it doesn't matter what the function tries, nothing works...

Comment: Why doesn't it work? are you getting a response back? in this case, Yes, you are getting a response back, it's is Internal Server Error which suggests the error is internal to your server (in other words, it's not related to javascript.) Therefore, you need to debug your server-side code. I suggest adding the proper tags to your question pointing to what server-side language you are using, and then looking for the server-side error text. We need more to go on than *"Internal Server Error"*.

Comment: I know and I agree with you, but the server side works just fine when i am trying to run it alone. This is what weirdest about all this.

Comment: Also, I opened a new Web Service, just to try and run it with ajax. It didnt work either.